# Which SDK for Importing existing Grails project to IntelliJ IDE?

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, groovy

I have created a new grails project which named is **helloworld** by console. And now, I want to import this project to IntelliJ IDE. At the one of steps, need to choose a project SDK.

Which one should I choose?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Java JDK ("JDK" in the pictured list).